# Silverstripe 4 get draft files in query

Tags: silverstripe

I'm very new to Silverstripe. I want to make draft files visible to logged in users.

When I execute a query like

```
File::get()->Where($query)
```

I only get published files.

How do I get all files for the logged in user with the permissions to view the file?

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Never tried this with files, but you could try querying them via `Versioned::get_by_stage()`

```
$draftFiles = Versioned::get_by_stage('File', Versioned::DRAFT)->where($query);
$liveFiles = Versioned::get_by_stage('File', Versioned::LIVE)->where($query);
```

See [here](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/model/versioning/) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Aaryn,

this works fine with Files,
but I dont get it work with a many_many relation saved in a 
DataObject.
when iterating through the dataobject the many_many field is always NULL.
in this field i saved uploaded, unpublished files.

foreach ($sitzungen as $item) {
    if ($item->MDateien() != NULL) {
       ...
    }
    ...
}

$sitzungen is the DataObject.
MDateien is the many_many field.

Thanks for your answer